# Executing script via Android app

Tags: android, shell

I have an Android app that I have installed as a system application (in /system/app) which is meant to execute a shell script passing a few variables that that user has set from within the app.
The code I am using is:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                        try{
                            Log.i("MyActivity", "trying");
                            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

                            outputStream.writeBytes("busybox chroot /uoa /bin/createuser.sh " + username.getText().toString() + " " + password.getText().toString());
                            outputStream.flush();

                            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
                            outputStream.flush();
                            su.waitFor();
                        }catch(IOException e){
                            Log.e("MyActivity", e.toString());
                        }catch(InterruptedException e){
                            Log.e("MyActivity", e.toString());
                        }
            }
```

However I get an error:

> E/MyActivity( 1872): java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken
>   pipe)

And the script does not get executed. I know the script works as I can run the command via adb shell.

> busybox chroot /uoa /bin/createuser.sh testuser test

Also how can I get the output from the script to log?